# set different hooks in react without duplicating code?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am learning typescript + react. I have the following form using reactjs and boostrap:

```
function ControlGroup(props: ControlGroupProps) {
  const [agentSettings, setAgentSettings] = useState("");
  const [agentQuestion, setAgentQuestion] = useState("");

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={(event) =>
        props.onAskAgent(props.agentData, agentSettings, agentQuestion, event)
      }
    >
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="agentForm.settings">
        <Form.Label>Set your agent settings</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          as="textarea"
          rows={3}
          onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setAgentSettings(value)}
          value={agentSettings}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="agentForm.question">
        <Form.Label> Ask your question </Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          as="textarea"
          rows={3}
          onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setAgentQuestion(value)}
          value={agentQuestion}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button className="center" type="submit">
        Ask agent
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

I have two different things I need to capture, agentSettings and agentQuestion. The code below works but I don't like how I have to type:

`{({ target: { value } }) => setAgentSettings(value)}`
and then
`{({ target: { value } }) => setAgentQuestion(value)}`

The code is almost identical other than the last bit. Is there a more elegant way to do this in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid question. Especially, when there are 10 input fields, you don't want to write the same code 10 times.

What's considered "standard" in this case is to use an object for storing form values and use one event handler for all input field changes, by using `name` attribute.

Something like this:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  inputA: '',
  inputB: '',
});

...

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  };
};


...
<input name="inputA" value={formData.inputA} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Comment: I think you mean "handleChange" on the last line. However, the code still does not work as I'm using typescript. What is the type of e (`FormEvent`)? If that is the case it complains that `name` doesn't exist as a value of target and neither does `value`. Setting `e:any` also doesn't work as both inputs now don't change (I suspect they're somehow reacting with each other).

Comment: `e`'s type is `SyntheticEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach when dealing with forms is to use Formik and Yup.
Formik is the most popular open source form library for React. It saves you lots of time when building forms and offers a declarative, intuitive and adoptable paradigm.
Yup is an open-source library that integrates perfectly with Formik. It allows you to set all your form validation rules declaratively.
First install both libraries:

```
npm install formik --save
npm install -S yup
```

After that:

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from 'yup';
```

The below code would go inside a React.JS component:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { firstName: '', email: '', comment: ''},
    onSubmit: (values) => {
    // Handle form submission
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      firstName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email address").required("Required"),
      comment: Yup.string().min(25, "Must be 25 characters at minimum").required("Required"),
    }),
  });
```

The way you would use this function is by spreading the returned object into the input elements:

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
<Input
  id="firstName"
  name="firstName"
  {...formik.getFieldProps("firstName")}                 
/>
<div>{formik.errors.firstName}</div>

<Input
  id="email"
  name="email"
  type="email"
  {...formik.getFieldProps("email")}    
/>
<div>{formik.errors.email}</div>

<textarea 
  id="comment" 
  name="comment" 
  rows={4}
  {...formik.getFieldProps("comment")} 
/>
<div>{formik.errors.comment}</div>

<button
type="submit"
disabled={!formik.isValid}
>
  Submit
</button>
</form>
```

Using TypeScript there are a few changes.
Here you can find **Formik TypeScript Support with a very good example for what you're looking for**: https://formik.org/docs/examples/typescript

Here you can find Yup TypeScript Support: https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/pre-v1/docs/typescript.md